# Sorting TObjectList<T> swaps equal values

Tags: sorting, delphi, tobjectlist

I have the following (simplified) class definition:

```
  TMyObject = class
  private
    FDoubleValue: Double;
    FText: string;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(ADoubleValue: Double; AText: string);
    property DoubleValue: Double read FDoubleValue write FDoubleValue;
    property Text: string read FText write FText;
  end;
```

The following sample code, shows how I am sorting the `TObjectList<TMyObject>` (`FMyObjects`) and displaying them in a `TListBox`.

```
constructor TfrmMain.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyObjects := TObjectList<TMyObject>.Create;
  FMyObjects.OwnsObjects := true; // Default but for clarity
end;

destructor TfrmMain.Destroy;
begin
  FMyObjects.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ii: Integer;
begin
  FMyObjects.Add(TMyObject.Create(100.00, 'Item 1'));
  FMyObjects.Add(TMyObject.Create(200.00, 'Item 2'));
  FMyObjects.Add(TMyObject.Create(300.00, 'Item 3')); // Duplicate sort value
  FMyObjects.Add(TMyObject.Create(300.00, 'Item 4')); // Duplicate sort value
  FMyObjects.Add(TMyObject.Create(400.00, 'Item 5'));
  ObjectsToListBox;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.SortList;
var
  Comparer: IComparer<TMyObject>;
begin
  Comparer := TDelegatedComparer<TMyObject>.Create(
    function(const MyObject1, MyObject2: TMyObject): Integer
    begin
      result := CompareValue(MyObject1.DoubleValue, MyObject2.DoubleValue, 0);
    end);
  FMyObjects.Sort(Comparer);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ObjectsToListBox;
var
  ii: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  for ii := 0 to FMyObjects.Count - 1 do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%d - %.1f - %s', [ii, FMyObjects[ii].DoubleValue, 
       FMyObjects[ii].Text]));
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SortList;
  ObjectsToListBox;
end;
```

Every time `Button1` is clicked (and the list sorted), `FMyObjects[2]` (Item3) and `FMyObjects[3]` ('Item4') swap position in the list.  In my "real world" (drawing) application this is undesirable.

I also experimented with different values for Epsilon in the `CompareValue` function call and also a different implementation of the anonymous function (comparing values and returning 1, -1 or 0), but neither seems to make a difference.

Am I missing something (e.g. a property that controls this behavior) or is this "by design" and it cannot be prevented?

Comment: This is because the Delphi sort implementers not stable. Which is fine for many applications, and by design. This has been discussed many times before here. Do a search for stable sort here. The TimSort implementation in spring4d is a stable sort. Which is the main reason why we added it.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The internally used Quicksort implementation is not a stable one, so reorder of equal items is expected. To make the sort stable you need to extend your comparer to take that into account. F.i. you can compare the *Text* properties when the *DoubleValue* properties are equal.

Comment: A common problem with today's software: only one column can be sorted, instead of being able to chain multiple columns. I usually use an `Array of Byte` for each column to sort where each byte stands for another column index, should the previous column's comparison result be equal.

Comment: @AmigoJack You can always make your Comparer function to accept two objects/record instead of just individual parameters from those objects and then compare individual parameters inside your Comaprer method in as many levers and any order that is needed.

Comment: @SilverWarior I do that. I was talking about so many others who don't.

Comment: That solution is a sticking plaster. By far the better approach is to use a stable sort